# Linux how to run a script in the background on a remote server?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, remote-server, gnu-screen

I'm on a linux machine.

I would like to run four perl scripts on a remove server. Each script produces a single output file but it can take hours to run. I would like to run the scripts in the background such that if I'm disconnected from the server or exit from the shell prompt, it will continue running. These script also print out lines to the command terminal as it's running. I would like to be able check the `print` statements the script is printing to the command terminal.

I would normally use the `screen -S` command to create a screen. Then press `CTRL+A CTRL+D` to deattach and `screen -r` to reattach to the screen but the remote server I'm on doesn't have screen. And I don't have sudo access to install it.

How do I run these 4 perl scripts at the same time in the background on the remote server?

Comment: Just a thought, but if screen isn't present, perhaps your provider doesn't want you to do leave long running background processes on their system.  Can you work with the provider to get it installed?

Comment: nohup <script.sh> & >> output.txt

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp the `script.pl` files already prints to an output.txt file. Will the command above print the command lines that `script.pl` generates?

Comment: @cooldood3490 Yes I believe it will work. Say your script.pl is printing out lines into a file called output.txt. If you run 'nohup <script.sh> & >> output-terminal.txt' you will also have a log of all the print command lines. nohup will prevent the process from being interrupted when you log out.

Answer (score 3):

GNU `screen` is the cleanest way. You don't need root permissions to install a local copy. You should be able to download the sources and do

```
tar -xzvf source.tar.gz
mkdir ~/local/
./configure -prefix=~/local/
make && make install
```

That would install `screen` in `~/local/bin`. However, if some dependencies are missing, you'll have to do that for each of them.

Comment: those commands don't seem to be working for me. what are the exact commands I need to enter? It sounds like I need to compile from source? can you post the steps to do that?

Comment: I assume you are using a major distro, why not just use the package manager?

Comment: Those are the exact commands. Download gnu screen sources and replace `source.tar.gz` in my instructions with the name of the downloaded file.

Comment: @kjprice he doesn't have admin access.